# SQL Query help - Percentiles

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a single table with 2 columns.

### Column

Student ID 
Course Id

Both these columns have many to many relationships with each other. 
I want to find out - 
1. Average number of courses registered by students across the set of all students. 
2. 90th percentile of the number of courses registered by all the students.

I have tried this using PERCENT_DISC() but somehow I have not been able to figure out.
Can anyone help me with this query ?

Comment: Post the queries you tried already so we can take it from there on

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle) and what version?

Comment: I am using oracle as the back-end database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your 1st question:

```
SELECT AVG(numCourses)
FROM(
        SELECT Cast(COUNT(CourseId) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) as numCourses
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY StudentID
) Grouped
```

Now about the percentile, If I'm fully getting what is asked in the question:
This 1st query is not the answer but will help understand it. It shows the number of courses per student as well as the discrete percentile over all students:

```
SELECT StudentID, count(CourseId)
       , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COUNT(CourseId))
        OVER (PARTITION BY 1) Percentile
FROM YourTAble
GROUP BY StudentID;
```

This query will show you the percentile:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5)
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COUNT(CourseId))
        OVER (PARTITION BY 1) Percentile
FROM YourTAble
GROUP BY StudentID
```

I placed this on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb3a0/6)

Comment: One of the queries that I tried was this - My intention was to find a 50th percentile in every group. However, what I want is 50th percentile over all the groups and not just a single group 
`code`
SELECT COURSE_ID,
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY numAssociations DESC) 
      "Median cont",
   PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY numAssociations DESC) 
      "Median disc"
   FROM(SELECT Cast(COUNT(STUDENT_ID) AS DECIMAL(16,2)) as numAssociations,COURSE_ID
        FROM MYTABLE
        GROUP BY COURSE_ID
) GROUP BY COURSE_ID

Comment: I think you want to count the number of courses per student. If this is not the result let me know.

Comment: The average query above tells us that on an average x students are registered for any course(Irrespecitve of the course).

On similar lines, I want to find out that 90th percentile of the students registered for any courses. I am looking for an estimate which will tell me that 90% of the times X students are registered for any course